# In GFXBench testing, what is the meaning of "OffScreen test"?

Tags: opengl

As title. Is that mean computation power of GPU?
What are the main differences of "OnScreen" and "OffScreen"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Screen = GPU drawing operations are performed on a region of memory that goes directly to the display output. Usually also means that the memory in question is managed by the windowing system.

Off Screen = GPU drawing operations are performed on a region of memory that *is not* directed to the display output and is managed by the program itself. Off Screen rendering is used to generate intermediary images in computer graphics, like reflection maps, shadow maps, postprocessing filters (motion or Depth of Field blur).

Comment: Well, if I want to compare power or efficiency of VGA card, I should notice the off screen scores ,right?